# How do I scroll down and up in my Nestedscrollview programatically with some delay?

Tags: java, android, android-nestedscrollview

I want to scroll down once and then up programatically. The scrolling should be slow and smooth. This is my code:

```
scroll_1.post(() -> scroll_1.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN));
scroll_1.postDelayed(() -> {
    scroll_1.smoothScrollTo(0,0);
},1000);
```

When I run the code, it scrolls down and up so fast, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your problem, replace the statement:

```
scroll_1.smoothScrollTo(0,0);
```

with the following:

```
ObjectAnimator.ofInt(scroll_1, "scrollY",  SCROLL_TO).setDuration(SCROLL_DURATION).start();
```

You have to replace `SCROLL_TO` with the position where you want to scroll to. If you want to scroll to the top, you can put `0` as the value.

`SCROLL_DURATION` is the duration in milliseconds that you want the `ScrollView` to take to scroll to a certain position.

If you want to scroll to the bottom, then you have to use `ScrollView.getBottom()`. Example code:

```
ObjectAnimator.ofInt(scroll_1, "scrollY",scroll_1.getBottom()).setDuration(SCROLL_DURATION).start();
```

Comment: Can I use the same logic for scrolling down?

Comment: @naive_6198 You should be able to use it for scrolling down too.

Comment: Strangely, when I scroll down using the code `ObjectAnimator.ofInt(scroll_1, "scrollY",  View.FOCUS_DOWN).setDuration(800).start();` it doesn't scroll all the way down to the bottom.

Comment: @naive_6198 Instead of using `View.FOCUS_DOWN`, you can use `scroll_1.getBottom()` to scroll to the bottom using ObjectAnimator. I have edited my answer to include the same.

Comment: it doesn't even scroll a bit when I use `scroll_1.getBottom`

Comment: That’s strange. I used ObjectAnimator.ofInt(scroll_1, "scrollY", scroll_1.getBottom()).setDuration(1000).start(); and it worked exactly as it’s supposed to